# Kden live window freezes and does not respond?

Tags: freeware, kdenlive

Hi guys I am just getting started with video editing and I have no previous experience with video editors. I use ubuntu, I have read in a blog post that kden live is the best video opensource video editor. It's freezing up whenever I am trying to use it. Can some one suggest a solution. FYI processor usage - 20%, mem usage - 40%. I have recorded these right at the time the program got stuck. I was looking at project monitor on a secondary display(I do not know if that's causing the issue).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Kden Live specifically, but a lot of times loading freezes are related to issues with either plugins or codecs.  If you just installed it, the most likely problem is probably an issue with codecs not loading.  Without a startup log though it's not really possible to give a better guess as to what is going on (and I'm not sure how you get that from Kden.)

Comment: That's always the issue with huge open source software with less support. Do you know any better opensource video editor software that run well on ubuntu?

Comment: I'd check and see if DaVinci Resolve works on it.  It isn't open source, but they have a free version.